# Azure table storage (Partition key row key), how to insert multiple entities in corresponding to same parttion and different rowKey?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I am a C# .net developer and I am creating an email tracking system. I want to store my data to the Azure Table Storage, but I want to create all the entities in the same partition with different row key. My properties key are same but the value is different. For example:

```
partition key = "Test+id"
row key=123
properties:
subject:"Hello",
from:"xyz@gmail.com",
to:"abc@gmail.com",
body:"Hello I am a test email"
```

Now I want to create a copy of above, but with different rowKey value, same Partition key-value and same property key but with different value. Like this:

```
partition key = "Test+id",
row key="787",
properties:
subject: "HelloTesting",
from:"sam@gmail.com",
to:"alex@gmail.com",
body: "Hello I am a test email2, this is so nice"
```

Here is the C# code that I am using to add the properties:

```cs
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in list)
{
    dynamicTableEntity.RowKey = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Key);

    if (keyValuePair.Key.Equals("subject"))
    {
        dynamicTableEntity.Properties.Add("subject", EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject(keyValuePair.Value));
    }
    else if (keyValuePair.Key.Equals("toRecipients") )
    {
        dynamicTableEntity.Properties.Add("toRecipients", EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject(keyValuePair.Value));
    }
    else if (keyValuePair.Key.Equals("from") )
    {
        dynamicTableEntity.Properties.Add("from", EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject(keyValuePair.Value));
    }
    else if (keyValuePair.Key.Equals("bodyPreview") )
    {
        dynamicTableEntity.Properties.Add("bodyPreview", EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject(keyValuePair.Value));
    }
    else
    {
        dynamicTableEntity.Properties.Add(keyValuePair.Key, EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject(keyValuePair.Value));
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome! Where are the code that you use to add in Azure Table? Can you provide more information?

Comment: CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(myStorageConnectionString);
                CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
                                                                                                       CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("MailCheckerSystem");
                await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
               // To insert
                    var tableOperation = TableOperation.Insert(dynamicTableEntity);
                    await table.ExecuteAsync(tableOperation);

Comment: What exception did you get? Though you might have resolved it as of now, it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Your code of inserting entity worked for me. Just to keep it simple, as you know the data type:

```cs
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in list)
{
    if (keyValuePair.Key.Equals("subject"))
    {
        dynamicTableEntity.Properties.Add("subject", EntityProperty.GeneratePropertyForString(keyValuePair.Value));
    }

    ...
}
```

As you didn't mention what exception you get, I assume there's a **RowKey** **conflict** when the row keys get the same value in one second as "SSS" used in DateTime has no effect. Try using `fff` or `FFF` to get [milliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-display-milliseconds-in-date-and-time-values).